# Does Hyperledger Fabric support Bip32-compatible HSM?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hsm

more context is that I'm looking forward to use some BIP-32 based hardware security module to 
be integrated with our Fabric network as an advanced security measure, does Fabric support this?

Actually, the question behind is that does Fabric allow users(end users under org) to own their own private keys?

Thank you very much if you could kindly give me some advices.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Fabric uses ECDSA for signatures.  The Fabric runtime components (peer, orderer, CA) all support PKCS11 for integration with HSMs.  The client SDKs support PKCS11 as well.